# What is a good estimate for $\sum_{t=0}^T \frac{1}{\gamma^t}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t + 1}}$, where $0 < \gamma < 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, upper-lower-bounds

Let $0 < \gamma < 1$ and $T$ be a "large" nonnegative integer.

### Question

> What is a good estimate (upper bound) for $\sum_{t=0}^T\dfrac{1}{\gamma^t}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{t + 1}}$?

In general, for $\alpha > 1$, I'm interested in estimating

> $\sum_{t=0}^T\dfrac{1}{\gamma^t}\dfrac{1}{(t + 1)^{1/\alpha}}$

Comment: Maybe I can compare with a corresponding integral ? Sorry, I've forgotten most of my elementary real analysis...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(1%2F(g%5Et*(t%2B1)%5E(1%2Fa)),+t,+0,+infty)), we can express (with $T = \infty$),
\begin{align*}
\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\gamma^t(t+1)^{1/\alpha}} = \gamma \text{Li}_{1/\alpha}\left(\frac{1}{\gamma}\right)
\end{align*}
where $\text{Li}_n(x)$ is the polylogarithm function. If you are looking for strict bounds in terms of elementary functions, then something like Holder's inequality gives us
\begin{align*}
\sum_{t=0}^{T} \frac{1}{\gamma^t(t+1)^{1/\alpha}} &\le \left(\sum_{t=0}^{T}\frac{1}{\gamma^{t\alpha/(\alpha-1)}}\right)^{1 - 1/\alpha}\left(\sum_{t=0}^{T}\frac{1}{t+1}\right)^{1/\alpha} 
\end{align*}
The first product on the RHS is a partial geometric series (with a closed-form). and the second is $H_{T+1}^{1/\alpha}$, where $H_n$ is the $n$th harmonic number, and this can be approximated very well with $\log$ and the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

EDIT: In Holder's, I applied with $p = \alpha/(\alpha-1)$ and $q = \alpha$. The resulting partial harmonic series doesn't converge, so the bound is quite weak. Applying with $p = 2\alpha/(2\alpha-1)$ and $q = 2\alpha$ will solve this issue.

Comment: Excellent answer thanks. Also thanks for the embedded mini-tutorial on how to use wolfram ;)